# Get number of bytes read from NetworkStream.EndWrite()

Tags: .net, networking, network-programming, tcpclient, networkstream

I need to get the number of bytes read from the stream. I can easily do this with

```
NetworkStream.Read();
```

however in order to do this whole operation async, I am using BeginRead() and EndRead().

```
private void NetworkEndWrite(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            _client.Stream.EndWrite(result);
        }

        private void NetworkEndRead(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            _client.Stream.EndRead(result);
        }

        #endregion

        public string UploadProgramFromGalil()
        {
            if (_client.Connected)
            {
                
                int numberOfBytesRead = 0; 
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                StringBuilder receivedData = new StringBuilder();

                if (_client.Stream.CanWrite)
                { //send the upload command and block until everything is sent.
                    _client.Stream.BeginWrite(Upload, 0, Upload.Length, new AsyncCallback(NetworkEndWrite), _client.Stream); //send the upload command
                }
                
                if (_client.Stream.CanRead)
                { //block until we get all of the data from the galil
                    _client.Stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(NetworkEndRead), _client.Stream); //reading this way does not return anything.
                    numberOfBytesRead = _client.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //reading this way gives me number of bytes read
                }

                receivedData.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead)); //take the bytes and build the string
                CurrentProgram = receivedData.Replace(":","").ToString();
                CurrentProgram = CurrentProgram.Replace("\u001a", "EN");
                return CurrentProgram;
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Client is Disconnected");
                return null; //TODO: handle this
            }
        }
```

EndRead() returns an int, but I am not able to change the return type of the callback.

so far the only option I see is to create a member NumberOfBytes read and use that. Is there a better option?

Edit: Also isn't the beginRead() supposed to be blocking? it always finishes before all the packets have made their way through.

Comment: normally, your completion callback would need that value anyway, so I'm not sure why it would matter, but: honestly, a better approach here is to switch to `async` and `await _client.Stream.ReadAsync(...)`

Comment: So in that case, the write would not be blocking, and the read would block until it has received all of the data? I am trying to overcome an issue of the program moving to fast, the other device cannot process fast enough, so I need to block until the packets are actually sent over the wire.

Comment: (btw, if you include @Marc, I'll get notified; I didn't notice your comment until now by chance) - `Read` only blocks until it has received "some" data, which means "at least one byte" (unless doing zero-length reads, but that's a side topic) - it isn't required to read the number of bytes you asked for, that's just an upper bound. You are *always* required to test what got returned and loop; although honestly, "pipelines" is usually the way to go here these days, especially if you're writing a server

Comment: (for context, "pipelines" is an alternative API designed for highly scalable IO, async-first, with advanced buffer management; Microsoft provides a server host, i.e. Kestrel, but I have made a client version, and a non-Kestrel server version, available in Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial; my multi-part blog series on "pipelines" [is here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html), and frankly, if you're trying to do anything network related, whether server or client, it is worth a look)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the information. I will definitely look into pipelines.